# How to determine if an object is within a camera's frame and its position within said frame knowing the camera properties and distance?

Tags: computer-vision

I will list camera and lens properties that may be of use.

- Camera resolution: 1280×1024 ((0,0) top left and (1279, 1023) bottom
  right)
- Lens Focal Length: 3.5 mm
- Sensor size and lens format: 1/2"
- Angle of view (1/2"): 77.8° x 105.9° (Diagonal: 136.8°)
- Pixel Size: 4.8μm

Now that these properties are known consider a point object 1m above the center of the lens (z axis), 55m to the right (x axis) and 80m away (y axis) (as seen in the image below).

[image]

Will the object be in view of the camera? If so in which pixel will it appear?

If the question is unclear, I'd be happy to elaborate further.

Answer (score 1):

You must calculate the horizontal and vertical field of view (FOW). This is just a simple trigonometry problem, denote by $f$ the focal length (3.5mm),by $W$ the sensor's width (6.4mm) and by $l$ the depht to the object (80m). Then the horizontal field of view at $l$ is

$$ FOV_h=2l\tan(\phi)$$
Where $\phi$ is the angle of view (in radians)
$$\phi=\tan\left(\frac{W}{2f}\right) $$

In the case of the vertical field of view, just change $W$ by $H$ the height of the sensor. In your case, to see the object you need that your $FOV$ to be greater than 55mx1m.

To see where your object you have to know the intrinsic parameters and the extrinsic parameters of the camera to calculate the projection matrix. Then you can calculate where the object will project up to a scale factor.